# Gradle build failes getting an error checkstyleMain FAILED

Tags: java, gradle, checkstyle

I recently upgraded my project.

```
   spring boot: 2.1.6 
   gradle: 4.10.2 
   java version 11
   jacoco : 0.8.1
   checkstyle: 8.1
```

My project build fails and getting the error:

Task :checkstyleMain FAILED

.gradle\daemon\4.10.2\etc\checkstyle\checkstyle-suppressions.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

Here is my gradle build file:

```
    jacoco {
       toolVersion = '0.8.1'
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        afterEvaluate {
           classDirectories = files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [
                       'com/emp/contacts/domain', 
  'com/emp/MyApplication.class'
               ])
           })
       }
   }

   checkstyle {
       toolVersion = '8.1'
       configFile = new File(rootDir, 'etc/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml')
       System.setProperty('checkstyle.cache.file', String.format('%s/%s', 
       buildDir, 'checkstyle.cachefile'))
   }
```

Here is my project structure:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got it working. Thanks for the hint Martin.

There was a totally different strategy when using java 11

Gradle checkstyle plugin searches for suppressions.xml within the daemon folder when using Java 11

this post has helped me
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8286

This is what I had to make in my project to make it work

In the build.gradle

```
checkstyle {
    configDir = file("$rootProject.projectDir/etc/checkstyle")  
}
```

In checkstyle.xml

```
<!-- Suppression file -->
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
   <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/checkstyle-suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to reference it alike this (these config XML can all be dropped into there):

```
configFile file("${project.rootDir}/config/checkstyle.xml")
```

The `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` should be found when declaring an absolute path.

Comment: @barfuin put them where you want, directory `config` is just less clutter.